# Python dataframe to_datetime syntax for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, syntax

I have a dataframe that contains columns a through f. columns b, d, and f are dates which I would like to make of type datetime, using pandas.to_datetime. Here is my code:

```
file = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=my_columns, engine='python')
df = pd.DataFrame(file)
df['b', 'd', 'f'] = pd.to_datetime(df['b', 'd', 'f'])
print('FINISHED')
```

However, when I execute my code, it seems to get stuck. I don't get any errors, but "FINISHED" never prints. I think my syntax on the to_datetime line is incorrect but I'm not sure why and I don't know how to fix it. My dataframe has about 1,000 rows in it. I am fairly new to Python. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don;t think this is legal syntax: `df['b', 'd', 'f']`, besides you should try passing `parse_dates=['b', 'd', 'f']` to `pd.read_csv` as you may need the post-processing step. The reason that may nto work is because this is stating that you have a column which is a tuple ('b','d','f')` which is probably going to raise a `KeyError` as it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example takes dates from excel that were saved as csv.

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
         a        b        c
0  ﻿1/1/17   1/1/17   1/1/17
1   1/2/17   1/2/17   1/2/17
2   1/3/17   1/3/17   1/3/17
7   1/8/17   1/8/17   1/8/17
8   1/9/17   1/9/17   1/9/17
9  1/10/17  1/10/17  1/10/17
```

Use coerce to avoid errors like this popping up.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Run the loop.

```
In [26]: for col in df.columns:
    ...:     df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], errors='coerce')
```

And you get your desired output.

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
           a          b          c
0        NaT 2017-01-01 2017-01-01
1 2017-01-02 2017-01-02 2017-01-02
2 2017-01-03 2017-01-03 2017-01-03
3 2017-01-04 2017-01-04 2017-01-04
4 2017-01-05 2017-01-05 2017-01-05
5 2017-01-06 2017-01-06 2017-01-06
6 2017-01-07 2017-01-07 2017-01-07
7 2017-01-08 2017-01-08 2017-01-08
8 2017-01-09 2017-01-09 2017-01-09
9 2017-01-10 2017-01-10 2017-01-10
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using the to_datetime method incorrectly. Try just doing

```
cols = ['b','d','f']
for col in cols:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(col)
```